# I need to create to Redundant VMs (both on 2 different datastores) via function

Tags: vmware, powershell-3.0

I have defined all the needed variables in a separate `Variable_Defination.ps1` file and have called it up here.
Is there a better way to do this?

I just want a script to create 2 redundant VMs both running on separate datastores and having Affinity rule set up for disaster recovery cases

```bsh
. ./Variable_Defination.ps1

function CreateRedundantVMs {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$ClusterName,
        [string]$ComputerName1,
        [string]$ComputerName2,
        [string]$sourcetemplate,
        [string]$InfraResourcePoolName,
        [string]$OSCustomizationspec,
        [string]$description
    )

    $Viabledatastores = (Get-Cluster $ClusterName | Get-Datastore) |
                        Where {$_.Name -like '*vSSD*'} |
                        Sort-Object FreeSpaceGB  -Descending |
                        Select -First 2 -ErrorAction 'Stop'
    if ($Viabledatastores) {
        $Viabledatastores
    } else {
        Write-Host "No Viable Datastores found"
        break;
    }

    Write-Verbose "`n---------------------- Creating redundant VMs now ------------------------`n " -Verbose
    New-VM -Name $ComputerName1 -ResourcePool $InfraResourcePoolName -Datastore $Viabledatastores[0] -Description $description -Template $sourcetemplate -OSCustomizationspec $OSCustomizationspec -DiskStorageFormat Thin
    New-VM -Name $ComputerName2 -ResourcePool $InfraResourcePoolName -Datastore $Viabledatastores[1] -Description $description -Template $sourcetemplate -OSCustomizationspec $OSCustomizationspec -DiskStorageFormat Thin
    Start-Sleep -s 3
    Write-Host "`n -------------------------------------------------------------------------`n "
    Write-Verbose -Message "Virtual Machine $ComputerName1 and $ComputerName2 Deployed. Powering On" -Verbose
    Write-Host "`n -------------------------------------------------------------------------`n "
    Start-VM -VM $ComputerName1
    Start-VM -VM $ComputerName2
}

# calling function
CreateRedundantVMs $ClusterName $ComputerName1 $ComputerName2 $sourcetemplate $InfraResourcePoolName $OSCustomizationspec $description
```

Comment: Is something not working? Otherwise [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a more appropriate place for getting critique on a working script.

Comment: I just added the above code within Try Catch Loop (keeping catch loop in a different script and calling it into the Main Script but it doesn't work somehow) 

Error : catch block is missing
Method of catch block script (CATCH.ps1)call  : (.  ./CATCH.ps1)

Comment: Ummm... *what?* What are you trying to achieve here? And why are you so hell-bent on scattering your code across different files?